# set correct error message validate in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i confuse to set a correct validate error message..

in model i set validate code like this

```
validates :tel, presence: { message: 'is required'}, length: { minimum: 10,  maximum: 11, message: 'wrong length tel number. must between 11-11 character' }, numericality: { message: 'just insert numeric'}
```

and in view page i set the code like this

```
<dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">tel number</dt>
    <dd><%= f.text_field(:tel, {:class => 'input_text tel'}) %>
         <% if @user.errors.include?(:tel) %>
            <div class="err"><p><%= @user.errors[:tel] %></p></div>
        <% end %>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

but the result like this
[image]

i dont want to display all the error message. what should i do if i want the error message display like this base on the error

[image]

Comment: can you try splitting the validation like `validates_presence_of :tel_number, :message => "can't be blank" validates_numericality_of :tel_number :message => 'must be numeric'` and see if it helps

Comment: @Subash check my answer. I am not sure above change would fix the issue. It will still check for numericality even if the `tel_number` is `nil`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use option [`allow_blank: true`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) on each validator if don't want them to validate your input when you didn't enter anything.

```
validates :tel,
          presence: { message: 'is required' },
          length: { minimum: 10,  maximum: 11, message: 'wrong length tel number. must between 11-11 character', allow_blank: true },
          numericality: { message: 'just insert numeric', allow_blank: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Rails` runs all the validation defined.
In order to achieve the desired result, you can either display the first message:

```
<dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">tel number</dt>
    <dd><%= f.text_field(:tel, {:class => 'input_text tel'}) %>
         <% if @user.errors.include?(:tel) %>
            <div class="err"><p><%= @ultratech.errors[:tel].first %></p></div>
        <% end %>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Or display them all, something like:

```
<dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">tel number</dt>
    <dd><%= f.text_field(:tel, {:class => 'input_text tel'}) %>
         <% if @user.errors.include?(:tel) %>
            <% @ultratech.errors[:tel].each do |error| %>
              <div class="err"><p><%= error %></p></div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </dd>
</dl>
```